# SSRS Report returning old data

Tags: ssrs, cache, visual-studio

I have created and tested a report in Visual Studio and it returns data from a SQL server database.
Once uploaded to SSRS, the report returns old data.

What would I need to check as it appears the data source has cached?

[image: Result in Visual Studio]

[image: Results from SSRS Report]

Update: I have created a table in the SQL database, and can query it from VS and report builder, but not from a report in SSRS.

Comment: How is your report set up? Are you using a stored procedure or query to return data?

Comment: I am running a query, using a shared datasource. I have also tested this with an embedded data source with the same result

Answer (score 0):

When a report is first run in Visual Studio, it creates a cache of the data that is used for all subsequent executions, as long as you don't change parameters. You can refresh the data by either changing parameters, or deleting this cache of the data.

To do so, navigate to your solution file and find the file for the report like `YourReport.rdl.data` and delete that. The next time you preview your report, it will query the database for the fresh data.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Another solution is to just press the refresh button within the preview tab of Visual Studio and it will rerun the query.